# How to add onto a dictionary value?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a csv file where each line contains a a bunch of random information separated by commas, and within it two teams and their scores. I want to make a dictionary that shows the team:score, and then every time a line appears where that team has won, the value should increase. Is there a way to append just the value? I was thinking something like:

```
wins = {} 
if line[4] > line[6]:
     wins.append(line[3] = value +=1)
```

where the data has been `split(",")`...but that's probably not even close.

P.S. the data line looks like this:

```
08/26/16,10:00:00 PM,California,51,Hawaii,31,ESPN,ANZ Stadium - Sydney AUS
```

Comment: No sample data, no code?

Comment: What are `line[7]` and `line[5]`? The comparison make it look like they're scores, but then the `.append()` line looks like `line[7]` is a team name.

Comment: You're totally right Barmar lines 5 and 7 are scores my mistake--  it should be append (line[4]) or line[6]

Comment: As for "will ... print as the teams": (1) the correct approach is to try it; (2) we cant' be sure, since you haven't bothered to *show* us what **lines** contains.  *I* sort of assume that it's the input line, split on commas, but ... well, *assume* ... you know ...

Comment: You guys are so funny I'm sorry!! I should have realized.  I added what an example line is and also deleted my question about the printing as teams

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase what you're trying to do, with the given data.

You have a dictionary **wins** that keeps track of team wins.  When you find that a team has won, you want to increment their **wins** value (not the key) by 1.

**append** is for *adding* entries to a list, making it longer.  It's not how you increment something, and it doesn't work on a dictionary.  The line that does the above is ...

```
wins[line[3]] += 1
```

Grab the team name, which is **line[3]**.  Using that as a key, reference the teams entry in **wins**.  Now that you have its attention, add 1.

Is that what you needed?

Comment: Cool thanks I think so!